# How to avoid mypy checking explicitly excluded but imported modules _without_ manually adding `type:ignore` (autogenerated)?

Tags: python, mypy

In the following MWE, I have two files/modules:

1. `main.py` which is and should be checked with mypy
2. and `importedmodule.py` which should not be type checked because it is autogenerated. **This file is autogenerated, I don't want to add `type:ignore`**.

#### MyPy Command

```sh
$ mypy main.py --exclude '.*importedmodule.*'
```

```sh
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.931
```

##### main.py

```py
"""
This should be type checked
"""

from importedmodule import say_hello

greeting = say_hello("Joe")
print(greeting)
```

##### importedmodule.py

```py
"""
This module should not be checked in mypy, because it is excluded
"""


def say_hello(name: str) -> str:
    # This function is imported and called from my type checked code
    return f"Hello {name}!"


def return_an_int() -> int:
    # ok, things are obviously wrong here but mypy should ignore them
    # also, I never expclitly imported this function
    return "this is a str, not an int" # <-- this is line 14 referenced in the mypy error message
```

But MyPy complains about the function that is not even imported in main.py:

> importedmodule.py:14: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "int")
> Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

What is wrong about my exclude?

Comment: @blhsing there was one important detail missing. The imported file is autogenerated from a .proto file. Therefor it is not a good solution to add `type: ignore` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: You can [override](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#using-a-pyproject-toml-file) `importedmodule` in `pyproject.toml` (or whichever config file you use, maybe `mypy.ini`) and set `ignore_errors = True` for that particular module. Note that `exclude` has one more drawback: if you run `mypy` on project dir (recursively), excluded file will be checked anyway (included files have higher precedence for some reason).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make [SUTerliakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14401160/suterliakov) comment on your question more visible, I would like to present it here again in more detail.

In the `pyproject.toml` file you can insert the following below your other mypy config

```ini
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "importedmodule"
ignore_errors = true
```

With this config you will ignore all errors coming from the mentioned module.

By using a wildcard, you can also ignore all modules in a directory:

```ini
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "importedpackage.*"
ignore_errors = true
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-exclude),

> In particular, `--exclude` does not affect mypy’s import following. You can use a per-module [`follow_imports`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html#confval-follow_imports) config option to additionally avoid mypy from following imports and checking code you do not wish to be checked.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there is a cli option for disabling mypy for unused functions in imported modules. When importing a module, mypy analyses all of it. The *static* analyser doesn't check if a function is used or not.

However you can silence any errors created in those imported modules

```
$ mypy main.py --follow-imports silent
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ mypy main.py --follow-imports skip
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the documentation reference :)
Now I see why all our tries did not succeed